# Fowarding Customer Subdomain to appspot subdomain in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, subdomain, cname

We are building a SAAS product that we would like to offer to our customer as installed/mounted product on their website.

i.e. our app is at http://saasproduct.appspot.com

and our two different customer's website is at http://www.cust1.com and http://www.cust2.com

Can I create cname record for www for cust1 pointing at cust1.saasproduct.appspot.com 
and cname record for www for cust2 poiting at cust2.saasproduct.appspot.com

is it possible ?

can I achieve something similar with Compute Engine ?

Answer (score 1):

The most reasonable is probably to follow the concepts here and use your own domain:

[Google Custom Domains](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/domain)

Essentially you would create cust1.saasproduct.com, cust2.saasproduct.com.  Both of which would have cname records to Google's servers and would serve your app.

Another option would be to make use of:

[Virtual IPs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/ssl#virtual_ip_vip)

Then you could just cname all your customer domains to a single app and presumably from that app check the domain name if you need to serve pages slightly differently.

It's conceivable you could also get the cust1.saasproduct.appspot.com, cust2.saasproduct.appspot.com names working.  HOWEVER you'd need to name your deployed versions cust1, cust2 which is definitely a bit of a hack and hard to maintain.

Comment: I could do it manually, but for hundreds of customer, it might be cumbersome, in that case, we will need definite answer for how reliable the hack is.